# Grails can't find class in jar

Tags: grails, jar, dependencies, classnotfoundexception

I am including a jar in my Grails project and am getting a class not found issue.

buildConfig.groovy

```
dependencies {
    compile "labServices:labServices:1.0"
}
repositories {
    flatDir name:'labServices',  dirs:'../LabServices/build/libs/'
}
```

-When I inspect the labServices jar it contains the classes

-When I inspect the .war it contains labServices.jar

-When I inspect the tomcat deployment of the war the WEB_INF/lib contains the jar

Code that is failing

```
//this is a class in the labServices.jar
def clarityCredentials = new Clarity("prod", "xxxx", "xxxx")
```

Error

> org.petermac.util.Clarity. Stacktrace follows:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.petermac.util.Clarity

I have run cleans, flushed the Ivy cache, deleted everything manually and still not working. Also it runs locally and through unit tests (so it is the war)

Note: The dependency-report shows no dependencies for labServices even though there are some. Could this be an issue?

I am relatively new to Grails (from Microsoft) so any tricks, ideas or debugging techniques would be great.

I am pretty sure it is classpath setup when deployed

**UPDATE**
Actual code  with irrelevance removed

```
import org.petermac.util.Clarity
public class LoadClarityController extends BaseController {
    def load() 
    {
        String samples = params.get("sampleIds")
        def clarityCredentials = new Clarity("prod", "apiuser", "1qaz@WSX")
    }
}

//in LabServices (jar is being included in war)
package org.petermac.util
public class Clarity
{
    public Clarity( server, username, password )
    {
    }
}
```

The path even appears in the META-INF (in the war). Also I have another external jar included which works fine? I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem!

Servlet.class was the root cause as this cannot be included in a grails project (tomcat provides this).

**Servlet.class** lives in **javax** library which gets included by **javaee** library which was included in the problematic jar so the load of **LabServices**.jar actually fails.

There was no easy way to find this.

***removing or excluding javaee from the LabServices module solved this.***

Answer (score 0):

Since it's in the WAR it's not a dependency issue, it would only be one if it was ignored in your IDE and/or `run-app` and/or not included in the WAR. All jars in `WEB-INF/lib` are included in the classpath, so it's probably structural. Does the package match the folder? If so it will typically work in tests and `run-app` but not when deployed to a container.

Ensure that the source includes

```
package org.petermac.util
```

and that `Clarity.class` is in `org/petermac/util/` in the jar.

Comment: Yes, Clarity.class is in org/.... but the source of LoadClarityController.class (from the war) does not make reference to the util.Clarity (none of the imports are.... Should it?

Comment: If the controller is in a different package from a class that it uses, you need an import, just like in any Java or Groovy class. But it's complaining that it can't find `org.petermac.util.Clarity`, so you must have imported that, right? What's the controller class?

Comment: I have added the bare-bones of the code at the bottom of the post under update. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: The path even appears in the META-INF (in the war). Also I have another external jar included which works fine? I am at a loss.